# What is the difference between Direct DCT and row and column DCT?

Tags: compression, dct

I understand that Direct DCT is fast compared to using row and column method, but how exactly does each one of them work? I have searched all over the internet but I can't seem to find any resources.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by "Direct DCT"

Comment: I meant FDCT and row column method, one of them applies DCT directly to the matrix whilst the latter converts it to 1D and then applies DCT, I wanted to know why FDCT is more computationally efficient

Answer (score 0):

Typically, DCT implementations reduce the DCT matrix to a produce of matrices Gaussian normal form. The matrices in the factorization are all diagonal matrices or matrices with entires on the diagonal and one off the diagonal. In most cases the diagonal entries are ones.

If you unroll a matrix multiplication after it has been factored like this, ones on the diagonal are NoOps and the one offs are a multiplications and additions.

Such factorizations greatly reduce the number of operations required.